# How to specify public key in RSACryptoServiceProvider .NET class

Tags: .net, rsa, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I need to sign an xml-doc with digital signature. I know that [there is a way to do this in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745(v=VS.90).aspx) but i cannot understand how to specify my own puplic key in RSACryptoServiceProvider. I need for the public key based on the special keyword. How can i do this? Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

For the Public Key Parameters, you can using [RSAParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsaparameters.aspx).

If you want to derive a key out of a phrase, look up the function PasswordDeriveBytes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.passwordderivebytes.aspx) .

Or, you can use applications such as Telnet or many PGP clients to create a public key out of a phrase.